# Selenium not working on Heroku (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir

Im using Selenium Webdriver on a Rails project, all is well on localhost but on Heroku I've had all kinds of issues, little by little I've been fixing them until i got this error (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError, session not created) , I have both GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN and GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM environment variables setup on Heroku and the line of code where I'm actually using it this looks like this

```
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, args: %w[--headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222]
```

One red flat might be that when I do

```
echo $GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM
```

on my Terminal it prints nothing..but I don't know if thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright , I figured it out what was wrong , I was creating multiple instances of `Watir::Browser.new`, now that i only create one instance, the `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError` has disapeared.

I wrote an article on how to configure Watir for Heroku to help other developers avoid this issue.

https://medium.com/@franciscoantunesbarreto1997/configuring-watir-with-ruby-on-rails-for-heroku-e96433854430

Answer (score 0):

This happens because heroku provide a default port, and you can't use your own port number, you can get the default port number by `int(os.environ.get('PORT',92222))`.

**So you need to change your chrome argument to**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT',92222))
options.add_argument(f'--emote-debugging-port={port}')
```